# MongoDB not saving changes

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have MongoDB serving as a backing store for my app. Have an update method there, as below:

```
updateEmployee(root, args) {
  return models.Employee.findById(args.input.id)
    .then(employee => {
      employee = Object.assign(employee, args.input)
      employee.save()
    })
    .then(response => response)
},
```

The `findById` is working fine, but `save()` does nothing - data in the database is not changed and I get `null` as response.

Comment: what's the actual context? Mongoose? it might be `insert()`

Comment: You want to return the promise from your `save` call: `return employee.save();`. That way, your second `then` call works on _that_ promise instead of the original one from `findById`. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the first argument returned by Mongoose (and Node in general) is not your data, but the error (if any).

So no, it's not working fine :) if you `console.log(employee)` with your current code, it will log `undefined` because the operation completed successfully, so there is no error.

You should write `.then( (error, employee) => { console.log(employee) }`

This is to encourage developers to manage errors.

**EDIT** : Apologies, I mixed up `then` and `exec`. Try the `exec` approach :

`.exec( (error, employee) => { console.log(employee) }`

Comment: This isn't right. [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes two callback parameters, one for resolve and one for reject (optional). The resolve callback only receives the successful result of the query, not the error. `exec` does what you're saying, but not `then`.

Comment: Oh that's right, I mixed up `then` and `exec`. Fixed that, thanks!